# adding a mathematical symbol in front of an item bullet

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I have, say an `\implies` symbol *before* each number in an enumerate environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to regulate the display of labels inside lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={$\implies\ \arabic*.$}, ref=\arabic*]
  \item First item.
  \item Second item.
  \item Last item.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item.
  \item Second item.
  \item Last item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Just to understand what's going on, suppose my enumeration is in the form of (a), (b) and so on... normally I have [(a)] as an option to the `\enumerate` command. How should I go about in this case?

Comment: I think I got it from the help file. Thanks :-)

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Using `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]` you're probably using the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) (although `shortlabels` provide similar functionality in [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)). `enumitem` just provides a broader spectrum of modifications to lists.